# Comparing the time complexity of two algorithms (inequality)

Tags: inequality, algorithms, computational-complexity

The question suggests two algorithms spend $T_A(n)=0.0001n^2$, and $T_B(n)=50 \sqrt n$, microseconds respectively, for a problem size of $n$. The question asks, at what input size will Algorithm $A$ become better than $B$. How do I find this?

I found a similar question with a solution that I don't fully understand. The running times of algorithms from a similar question are $T_A = 0.1n^2\log_2 n $ and $T_B = 2.5n^2$

It's solved as follows:

$2.5n^2 < 0.1n^2 \log_2 n$
    $2.5 < 0.1 \log_2 n$
    $25 < \log_2 n$
    $2^{25} < n$

Therefore, Algorithm $B$ is better when $n$ is greater than $2^{25}$

I understand the concept of having to use inequality to prove that $0.0001n^2 < 50 \sqrt n$, however, am having a hard time understanding what's being done in the solution for the example, and how to apply it to the question...

Comment: I think Your Question is a little incorrect one. This is because of $n^{3/2}$ cannot be bounded by a constant quantity when $n\rightarrow\infty$ or put another way when $n$ is large enough, it cannot be bounded by any constant.

Comment: @Kumar I suppose it's possible, though I feel it may be more likely that I phrased it differently than how I have it, so I'll reiterate it verbatim, and hopefully, that might help clear things up. "Algorithms A and B spend exactly TA(n) = 0.0001n^2 and TB(n) = 50√ microseconds, respectively, for a problem of size n. Determine the problem size  n0 for which the “better” algorithm begins to outperform the other assuming n0  >  0."

Comment: The last statement of your comment should be your actual question rather than a comment. and whatever, I said is given as an answer @DavideFiocco.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.0001+n%5E2+%3D+50+%5Csqrt+n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the two algorithms solve the same problem. In that case you can say that Algorithm A is better than B if $T_A$ < $T_B$, because the former runs in a shorter time.

For which (positive) values of n does that $T_A$ < $T_B$ inequality hold? Substituting the expressions of $T_A$ and $T_B$ you get

$0.0001 n^2 < 50 \sqrt n$.

You can learn how one can solve an inequality of this kind with pen and paper e.g. [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:solve-equations-inequalities/x2f8bb11595b61c86:multistep-inequalities/v/multi-step-inequalities-3), or solve it graphically and algebraically [using an engine for symbolic math](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.0001n%5E2+%3C+50%E2%88%9An) like Wolfram Alpha. If you do that, you will see that $T_A$ is smaller than $T_B$ only if n is smaller than some threshold value. Beyond that threshold, algorithm $B$ "gets better than $A$" because a square root function (like $T_B(n)$) increases more slowly than a quadratic one (like $T_A(n)$) as n increases.

Comment: @Varehen Consider deleting the same question posted on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58019830/comparing-the-time-complexity-of-two-algorithm :)